# How to parse an variant Json using Circe library with Scala?

Tags: json, scala, circe

I'm trying to create a decoder for my Json model using case classes but i cannot find the way to decode a variant list of jsons.

```
object CirceTester {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val json = """{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "123.34",
  "list of stuff": [ "4", "5", "6","24545","435.030" ],
  "jsonlist": [ {"name":"Jesus","age":20},{"name":"Pedro","age":45}]
}
"""


     case class Person(name:String,age:Int)

    implicit val decodePerson : Decoder[Person] = {

      Decoder.forProduct2("name","age")(Person.apply)

    }

    val parsedJson = parse(json)


    val list = parsedJson match {
      case Left(parsingFailure) => throw new Exception("Failed to parse Json")
      case Right(parsedJson) => parsedJson.hcursor.downField("jsonlist").as[List[Person]]


    }

  }       
}
```

If the Json is written this way it works fine but if Json has a list of variant Jsons which is the case of jsonlist, the code will fail.

For example

```
val json = """{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "123.34",
  "list of stuff": [ "4", "5", "6","24545","435.030" ],
  "jsonlist": [ {"name":"Jesus","age":20},{"name":"Pedro"}]
}
"""
```

In this case, the second element of jsonlist is another Json that lacks the field "age", and as I said it will throw an Exception. Can i manage to parse that nested Json even if it doesn't follow exactly the structure of the case class

Comment: There is `Option` exists for optional fields. Is there any reasons why you don't want to refactor your model to `case class Person(name: String, age: Option[Int])`?

Comment: Thank you very much @YevheniiPopadiuk, i didn't know I could use Option in this case, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As it clear now that questions stands about reading optional values from json.*

Changing model to fit json structure you trying to parse is one of the best choices here. So in this case `age` filed must to be optional:
`case class Person(name: String, age: Option[Int])`.

If you cant change your `Person` definition you can define intermediate `case class PersonRecord(name: String, age: Option[Int])` and write custom `def toPerson: Person` method inside - this way it is clearer then creating custom logic in json readers.